# vite - create-vite got error in node version 18

Tags: vue.js, vite

I am using `yarn create vite` to create my vue project, but after executed command I got following error message:

> error expo-cli@6.0.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12 <=16". Got "18.1.0"
> error Found incompatible module.

I know that error message means I need to use node version between 12~16, but I am confused that there's no mentioned node version 18 cannot use in vite document.

[image]

Also, in the [package.json](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/packages/create-vite/package.json), there's only limit on *14.18.0* or *16+*

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not with vite but with expo-cli as it says right at the start of your error message: `error expo-cli@6.0.2:`.  As the expo-cli [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/installation/) state:

> Only Node.js LTS releases (even-numbered) are recommended

The latest node LTS version being 16.17.1