# ReactJS 18 and vite 4 import-analysis error in npm run dev

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

please, I have problem with `Vite` server and `ReactJS`

Version of ReactJS:

```bash
fox@mustang:~/projects/nazory.sk$ node -v
v18.14.0
fox@mustang:~/projects/nazory.sk$ npm -v
9.3.1
```

I'm getting **vite import-analysis** problem. The Error is:

```
2:39:47 PM [vite] Internal server error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. If you are using JSX, make sure to name the file with the .jsx or .tsx extension.
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: /home/fox/projects/nazory.sk/src/components/aside.js:6:30
  2  |  function Aside() {
  3  |    return <aside>
  4  |        <h2>Discussion Panel</h2>
     |                                 ^
  5  |      </aside>;
  6  |  }
      at formatError (file:///home/fox/projects/nazory.sk/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:41389:46)
      at TransformContext.error (file:///home/fox/projects/nazory.sk/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:41385:19)
      at TransformContext.transform (file:///home/fox/projects/nazory.sk/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:39628:22)
      at async Object.transform (file:///home/fox/projects/nazory.sk/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:41660:30)
      at async loadAndTransform (file:///home/fox/projects/nazory.sk/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:39466:29)
```

From this component

```js
import React from 'react'

function Aside() {
  return (
    <aside>
      <h2>Discussion Panel</h2>
    </aside>
  )
}

export default Aside
```

File is named `'components/aside.js'`

But for example my Header is OK and it's the totally same

```js
import React from 'react'

function Header() {
  return (
    <header className="header">
      <h1>Názory.sk</h1>
      <div>Žurnalistika ľudí - Články a slobodné diskusie bez reakcií na diskutujúcich</div>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

File is saved as `components/header.js`

I'm importing and using in `App.jsx` my all components

import Header from './components/header'
import Article from './components/Article'
import Aside from './components/aside'

```js
function App() {
  // Render compoment
  return (
    <main className="container">
      <Header />
      <Article />
      <Aside />
      <footer className="footer">&copy;2023 - Frisky Fox</footer>
    </main>
  )
}

export default App
```

One important thing:

> If I have also `footer.js` in components the error is there. It's always on the last component.

My package.json

```json
{
  "name": "nazory.sk",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "vite": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

My vite.config.js

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

I have only LTS ReactJS so answer here doesn't help:

[vite - create-vite got error in node version 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73968250/vite-create-vite-got-error-in-node-version-18)

Btw, I've tried using Brackets, without brackes if I had only `return <footer></footer>`. I've tried also using semi set to prettier, nothing helps. And always is error on the last impotent component. The reason why I have error on `aside.js` is that I haven't `footer.js` like component. If I create new component for footer and call id in App.js the error will in `footer.js`

I think that this sould be vite bug, couldn't be?

Comment: Could you rename the file extensions from .js to .jsx, the error seems to be about that!

Comment: Yes. It's working, sorry. But I must rename every component. Not only the one :) Thank you sou much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options

first one is what [YHR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13760612/yhr) said but the problem is as you said to change all files extenstion

the second solution is to just add this config to your vite.config.js

```
 defineConfig({
  esbuild: {
    loader: 'jsx',
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      loader: {
        '.js': 'jsx',
      },
    },
  },
  ...
```

as it shows, it just telling vite loader to consider js as jsx

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth I had that error display recently for three different files, two components and one custom hook. My project is a React TypeScript and was going through a conversion from `react-scrips` to `vite`.

It took me a couple of days to figure out that one import used in only these three files and no other was the culprit and it hadn't been converted from JS to TS. I am wondering if Vite import syntax analysis has an issue with JS files imported into TS files.

I hope this helps anyone having the same issue.